# How to execute specific HTTP request using robotframework

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

below command will execute all the HTTP request under the jmx file but i want to execute specific threadgroup or HTTP request in jmeter using robot framework.

Below keyword will execute all the threadgroup and HTTP request,

```
Run Jmeter    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx     ${logPath}  -Jvendor=${vendor} -Jurl=${url} -Jport=${port}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - if you dynamically define the number of threads using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2 thread groups like:

   - in Thread Group 1: `${__P(thread.group.1.users,)}`
   - in Thread Group 2: `${__P(thread.group.2.users,)}`

   [image]

   you will be able to provide the desired number of threads via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   - Run thread group 1 with 100 users, don't run thread group 2: `/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx     ${logPath}  -Jvendor=${vendor} -Jurl=${url} -Jport=${port} -Jthread.group.1.users=100 -Jthread.group.2.users=0`
   - Run thread group 2 with 100 users, don't run thread group 1: `/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx     ${logPath}  -Jvendor=${vendor} -Jurl=${url} -Jport=${port} -Jthread.group.1.users=0 -Jthread.group.2.users=100`
   - Run both thread groups with 100 users each: `/home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.sh    /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/HTTP Request.jmx     ${logPath}  -Jvendor=${vendor} -Jurl=${url} -Jport=${port} -Jthread.group.1.users=100 -Jthread.group.2.users=100`
2. The same approach can be applied to the HTTP Request samplers, if you put them under the [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) and use __P() function as the switch value like `${__P(request,)}`:

   [image]

   - if you pass `-Jrequest="Request 1"` - it will execute `Request 1`
   - if you pass `-Jrequest="Request 2"` - it will execute `Request 2`
   - etc.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)